# Banned from asking questions, but it is unclear why

Tags: support, post-ban

I was banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow, but it is not clear why. If there is a valid reason, then fine, but I do not know what I have done wrong.

In [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), it says:

> Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban questions from accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past. These filters help keep the quality of our sites high. The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, ***but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site.***

(Click images for links to posts)

However, the only post I can find that I have written that was down-voted is this:

[image]

All my other questions:

[image]

Have been well-written in my opinion (excluding the JRE7 question, but I could not say it was BADLY written either):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would also like to point out that I have answered several questions and got positive votes from that:

[image]

I have been unable to find any deleted posts (except the one already mentioned near the top of the post).

So is it possible that someone could please just tell me what I did wrong, why/how I was banned, and what I can do to lift the ban?

Edit: Just to clarify, I am asking for clarification on what it says in the "Help center", because what it says in the help center is contradictory to what actually seems to have happened. I have already tried editing existing questions and helping others, but I have never got unbanned.

Comment: Do you have deleted questions that were downvoted?

Comment: @Woobie Only the deleted question that I showed at the top. I cannot find any other deleted questions.

Comment: You have two fairly heavily down-voted deleted questions - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367987/eclipse-how-to-use-team-sychronizing-mode) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877252/what-debian-equivalent-is-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: It's not really **contradictory** because 40% of your questions were down-voted and closed. That doesn't really bode well for your future question asking potential. I had a heavily down-voted question for one of my first questions posted on SO. I learned from it, read every article, guide, blog post, question, and FAQ I could find on asking better questions. You posted screenshots for two other questions with 0 votes. That means the community doesn't find them useful. Taken all together, you lost your privilege to post here. That is not contradictory at all. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: I sympathize with the OP, because it's very easy to have a particular question get the attention of a particular crowd and be heavily down-voted.  (In some cases apparently folks go onto chat groups to get others to down-vote a question.)  If this happens after you've become fairly well established then it's no biggie, but if it happens early in your membership then it could be a killer.

Comment: Neither here nor there, but when it's "user#####" instead of a name or nym, I'm less likely to help.

Comment: It is notable that there's no such downvoting issue on math.stackexchange.com. stackoverflow, on the other hand, is known for downvoting peoples' questions very easily. I don't know exactly why this happens, but it would certainly be interesting to learn why. I don't think that math askers necessarily ask higher quality questions more often.

Comment: @sequence I don't know about math.stackexchange.com, but from my experience on SO (mostly concerning the Java tag) lots of questions are duplicates, show little to no research effort or are blatant homework dumps/requests for code.

Comment: @ModusTollens On math, people don't downvote for duplicates.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have 5 questions; two of which are deleted:

- [What debian is equivalent to Ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877252/what-debian-equivalent-is-ubuntu-12-10)
- [Eclipse: How to use Team sychronizing mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367987/eclipse-how-to-use-team-sychronizing-mode)

These questions were heavily downvoted; and since downvotes are an indicator of value, we can deduce that these downvoted and deleted questions are hurting you (as the help center states):

> users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts.

One of your questions looks like it was downvoted because you were negative towards those trying to help:

> Sedond Edit: I asked on the spigot forums and got a lot more
>   constructive awnsers which have eventually solved my problem using the
>   Sayros eclipse plugin.
>
> The Sayros eclipse plugin allows me to in real-time share and code
>   with others.
>
> And yes to one of the comments i am part of a programming team, i am
>   actually the lead of the team, and it was suggested to me that using
>   the team sychronizing mode of eclipse was a good idea. As it is, the
>   Sayros plugin has greatly reduced the time we need to code things.
>
> Edit: Thanks for many of the non-helpful awnsers. Of course i dont
>   know what CVS is, which is exactly why i am asking. Telling me that i
>   dont know something that i already know i dont know isnt going to
>   help.

Berating the community isn't a great way to get upvotes.  These comments directly led to the questions closure, downvoting, and deletion.

The help center is also correct that just one 'bad post' will not hurt you; it appears you have three.

[Your latest question was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272303/jbullet-moving-an-entity-while-also-allowing-collision-detection?noredirect=1) because you linked to the code in a third-party site, but when I go to visit that site, the code doesn't show up.

The code should be pasted into the question, *not on a third party site*, for which I hope are obvious reasons, given what actually happened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Many of these questions were asked a long time ago, and I had totally forgotten asbout the ubuntu question.

With the Team Sychronizing, I simply felt that people were being mean to be just because of my lack/inaccuracy of knowledge of what I had been told by other people.

I have tried pasting code into a question, however I have tried using [Code] blocks to no effect. Clicking the "Code" button makes it say it has to be some format or other, which I cant work out.

Anyway. Now I know what I did wrong, how can I undo what I did wrong and be able to post questions?

Comment: @Joehot200 Actually the way to get out of the ban is described in the help center (that is linked in your question).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I got out of the ban months ago.