# Question ban; followed instructions, not sure what to do next

Tags: support, post-ban

I've been question banned.  The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) says to edit all of your posts and contribute to the site to get unbanned.  I have edited ***all*** of my questions, added solutions to my questions where appropriate, marked answers accepted where appropriate, and looked for deleted questions (I see 0 deleted questions).  [I've](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269866/question-ban-incorrect) [read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271286/question-ban-problem) a [few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255578/what-triggers-the-question-ban) posts [on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293647/question-ban-progress-tracker-is-it-possible) meta, and it seems that the system can just [pointedly screw you over (comment #1)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269869/2484483).

I don't have that many questions here on SO (only 14), so I'm not sure what to do next.  I have been editing questions to gain rep for the past week or so, and have improved my rep by 25% - 50% depending on how you calculate it (30 - 40 points in absolute terms).  You can see my rep curve is trending upward and has no downward spikes, and looks pretty good for a not-so-active user:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see that I have 0 unhelpful flags cast against me:

[image]

Is my account screwed over, or are there other things I can do?

I don't expect any new traffic to my questions to garner upvotes.  The topics I ask questions are not as common as they were years ago, and I see way more questions than answers in those categories.  The questions I ask may be specific to my application, but I don't see them as substantially more specific than other questions in the tags/categories I am asking.

I read the automated suggested posts as well. [Link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253595/banned-from-asking-questions-but-it-is-unclear-why), [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278937/got-banned-from-stackoverflow-for-what-i-think-unfair-reasons-how-i-get-my-repu), [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345617/im-very-uncertain-why-my-questions-on-so-were-deemed-low-quality-and-my-account), [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274457/how-strict-is-the-bad-question-ban-filter).

The accepted answer in the second [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278937/got-banned-from-stackoverflow-for-what-i-think-unfair-reasons-how-i-get-my-repu) states that there are warnings prior to a ban.  I do not recall ever seeing one, let alone multiple, nor do I know how those would be delivered (email?)

Comment: You might read [this FAQ on question bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/215552).

Comment: Forgot to reference that one.  I had already come across it and star'd it.

Comment: You can't see flags *against* you. But you're looking for  >0  helpful flags. That will not help in getting the ban lifted by the way.

Comment: Oh, and it takes time for posts to get upvotes. Don't expect those within the hour, I would more expect days if not weeks.

Comment: Looks like your first attempt at a userforms question the same day of your last question was downvoted (quite heavily) closed and deleted (and is more than 60 days old so won't show on the deleted recent). That's going to be the trouble here.

Comment: By the way - the flags page you're showing is showing how many helpful flags you've cast yourself - that is, these aren't flags against your account.  That's not what that view is telling you.

Comment: I thought flagging was something you only did when you wanted a mod to delete something or someone.  This is the first I've heard of it on any SE.  I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Have requested the CM team to disassociate the post from your account. If/when they do - I don't know- so you'll have to be patient I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonClements Are there any plans to address this issue? It's somewhat unfair to have the help center tell you to fix your old questions; and then go ahead and prevent you from doing that on old questions. What's the reasoning from not simply showing *all* deleted posts?

Comment: @rob basically as far as I understand it, it is because of [loss aversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion)